# Why is maven re-downloading the required plugins?

Tags: maven, mirror

After I set a new *mirror* to overwrite the *central responsitory*, I try to execute 'mvn clean', then I get the following output:

.....

[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar

[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)

Why did it re-download, and why does it say '0 B at 0.0 KB/sec'

Comment: might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421454/why-maven-is-downloading-metadata-every-time

Comment: Maybe it is trying to get the latest plugin? but that can be setted by myself? and where?

Comment: I think the answer is in the link I added above. I would try to change the updatePolicy in settings.xml for that repository. At least for the plugin repository. Also make sure all plugins in your pom.xml have a version. There should be a warning if version information is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't re-download in this case.

If you re-read the messages it says

```
[INFO] Downloading...
```

and then

```
[INFO] Downloaded...
```

The first message is telling you of the attempt to download. The second is telling you the result (that it downloaded the plugin and the network performance for the download.)