# HBase Indexer to work with Apache HBase

Tags: hadoop, solr, hbase

I am getting the below error when building with Apache Hbase. 
I am running the below mail

`mvn -e clean install -DskipTests -Dhbase.api=0.98`

``` [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).

Project ID: null:akuma:jar:1.9

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.kohsuke:pom for project: null:akuma:jar:1.9 for project null:akuma:jar:1.9

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.kohsuke:akuma:jar': Cannot find parent: org.kohsuke:pom for project: null:akuma:jar:1.9 for project null:akuma:jar:1.9
  org.kohsuke:akuma:jar:1.9

from the specified remote repositories:
  default (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  cdh.repo.snapshots (https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/),
  ngdata.oss-releases (http://mvnrepo.ngdata.com/content/repositories/oss-releases)

Path to dependency: 
    1) com.ngdata:hbase-indexer-server:jar:1.6-SNAPSHOT

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:711)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.kohsuke:akuma:jar': Cannot find parent: org.kohsuke:pom for project: null:akuma:jar:1.9 for project null:akuma:jar:1.9
  org.kohsuke:akuma:jar:1.9
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the hbase indexer, for the hbase-indexer-server module, in pom, you will have

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
      <artifactId>akuma</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Looks like, while fetching the dependencies, that jar is not being fetched and not present in repository. Try to get correct version with dependencies built. Normally this is the jar needed for the indexer-server module ".m2\repository\org\kohsuke\akuma\1.9\akuma-1.9.jar"

Comment: The above property is already existing in the pom file. Regarding the jar, it was not available at this path.  `m2\repository\org\kohsuke\akuma\1.9\akuma-1.9.jar`     I downloaded it and even added the same jar manually but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: I can see this "Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.kohsuke:akuma:jar': Cannot find parent: org.kohsuke:pom for project: null:akuma:jar:1.9". Looks like there might be some problem with the metadata file. Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421454/why-maven-is-downloading-metadata-every-time), for similar issue - not exact error but the way the meta data is being fetched. You can try with updatePolicy as **never** for snapshot and **always** for relese element under repository

Comment: This worked with maven 3.3.3   I was using maven 2 before. For further details refer to this **[link](https://github.com/NGDATA/hbase-indexer/issues/64)**