# Intellij idea both download dependencies using maven UI and terminal

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I import a maven project in my intellij idea , and select auto download sources and documents.

After I imported, idea downloads the dependencies automatically.

But when I use `mvn install` in idea's terminal, it downloads those dependencies again.
I have set the idea's maven to be the same with terminal's maven in `File->Settings`, still haven't figured out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I use mvn install in idea's terminal, it downloads those dependencies again.

Double-check *what* it actually downloads: if your maven repository cache (by default ~/.m2/repository) is the same, maven will still download the `maven-metadata.xml` files: see "[Why is Maven downloading the `maven-metadata.xml` every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16425036/6309)"