# Preventing maven downloading maven-metadata & plugin artifacts everytime

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am observing whenever I am executing the below command:-

```
mvn -f pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_REPO -Drat.skip=true -DnoTest=true surefire-report:report
```

maven is downloading `maven-metadata` & plugin artifacts every time.

```
Downloading: http://maven.twttr.com/com/neveda/kekin-storage-metrics/0.001-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml 

...

Downloading: http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/libs-release/org/
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421454/why-is-maven-downloading-the-maven-metadata-xml-every-time/16425036#16425036) answer & my `settings.xml` looks like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <snapshots>
           <enabled>false</enabled>
           <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots>
         <id>central</id>
         <name>libs-release</name>
         <url>http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/libs-release</url>
       </repository>
       <repository>
         <snapshots>
          <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots> 
         <id>snapshots</id>
         <name>libs-snapshot</name>
         <url>http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/libs-snapshot</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
       <pluginRepository>
         <snapshots>
           <enabled>false</enabled>
           <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
         </snapshots>
         <id>central</id>
         <name>plugins-release</name>
         <url>http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/plugins-release</url>
       </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
     <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
     </snapshots>
         <id>snapshots</id>
         <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
         <url>http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/plugins-snapshot</url>
       </pluginRepository>
     </pluginRepositories>
     <id>artifactory</id>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Environment:-

- Maven - 3.5
- OS - 10.12.6

Comment: Are you having SNAPSHOT dependencies? Please show your full pom file.

Comment: Yes I have SNAPSHOT dependency. It is a multimodule project. Do you want all the poms?

Comment: Do you have SNAPSHOT dependencies outside the multi module project? If the SNAPSHOT deps only intermodule dependencies that should not result in downloads from repository if so something is wrong...

Comment: I am seeing releases also getting downloaded. For example `Downloading: http://artifactory.kekin.local:XXXX/plugins-release/commons-digester/commons-digester/a.b/commons-digester-a.b.pom`

Comment: Are you deleting everytime the local cache ($MAVEN_REPO) ?

Comment: I do `mvn clean install -DskipTests -T 6` and then `mvn -f pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_REPO -Drat.skip=true -DnoTest=true surefire-report:report` . As per my understanding `clean` don;t delete the local repo.

Comment: The question is how your job is configured cause it looks like you are running inside a CI solution like Jenkins otherwise your calling from command line with so many parameters does not make sense...?

Comment: The commands that I have posted in my question is in my local dev machine, MacOS , 10.12.6. But I don;t think having the parameters in command line is anything to do with download issue I am facing.

Comment: Please add the full pom file to your pom...

Comment: Sorry @khmarbaise I did not get you.Can you please explain what do you mean by "add full pom file to your pom" ?

Comment: Just add the pom file you are using in this case to the post...?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would be a solution for you but you can invoke maven with the `--offline` switch to stop it from doing any downloads:

```
mvn --offline  -f pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_REPO -Drat.skip=true -DnoTest=true surefire-report:report
```

This has the side-effect, though, that your build will fail if any artifact is missing.

Comment: I know about `-o` but I want something like if the artifact is missing or have been modified then only download.

Comment: The other side effect you have here is that any SNAPSHOT dependencies will not be updated, if you care about that, the offline mode is all or nothing, and there's nothing to do about that